# javah.exe not included in Windows JDK 8?

Tags: netbeans, java-8, java-native-interface, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to learn JNI on Windows 7 64-bit, but JDK 8 does not include javah.exe. I tried both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions. The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) shows that javah is part of JDK 8 and doesn't make any platform distinction. Is there a separate download for JNI?

Also, the tutorials that I could find on JNI on Windows are pretty old - is there a newer way to do JNI in Windows, or does anyone have any suggestions for current Windows JNI Tutorials? NetBeans is my preferred IDE, but I'm not exclusive.

Comment: Well, it *is* still there, though there are *long-term* plans to remove it. `javac` can generate the native headers while compiling the java source code. Mind the `-h` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hej Kevin, there is no seperate download needed for JNI and javah.exe is included in your JDK, search for it in `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` (if you don't have set this environment variable, look into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin` or the version you have). Make sure you have downloaded the JDK, not JRE. And, the best JNI tutorial to start with is indeed [that one](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html), at least for me it was.

Comment: Yep - I overlooked the obvious - %JAVA_HOME% was set to the jre folder instead of jdk, and I didn't realize the jdk was a different folder thanks!